# Nativescript and angular 2 Http service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nativescript

I m learning native apps through javascript technologies, and I m trying to build a simple application using the pokemon api available only.

**What I've done**

I've created a simple component that list some pokemons, resulting from an http response :

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector:'pokemon-list',
  templateUrl: 'components/pokemonList/pokemonList.html'
})
export default class PokemonList implements OnInit{

  pokemons: Array<any>;

  constructor(private http:Http){
    this.pokemons = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getRemote(); // I pass on here
  }

  getRemote(){
    this.http
      .get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/') // Throws the weird error
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.pokemons = res.results;
      });
  }
}
```

**My problem**

When I start my application, I'm getting a weird error

```
Error in app.component.html:4:4 caused by: null is not an object (evaluating '_angular_platformBrowser.__platform_browser_private__.getDOM().getCookie')
```

*I've to notice that this error only happens if the getRemote body is set with my http call. Moreover, when I set a default pokemon in my pokemon list, with the API result format like {name: 'Name', url: 'url}, the app is working and the pokemon well displayed.*

If I remove the code like following, the app is working. It seems that I'm missing something with the Http module right there :

```
getRemote(){
    // App is running without the Http call
  }
```

NB : I'm using TS 2+ && I've set the Http module in my current module using :

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/platform";
import PokemonList from './components/pokemonList/pokemonList.component';
import PokemonItem from './components/pokemonItem/pokemonItem.component';
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      PokemonList,
      PokemonItem
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
      NativeScriptModule,
      HttpModule
    ],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your NgModule instead of *HttpModule*, you should import the NativeScript wrapper **NativeScriptHttpModule**  as shown here https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/blob/master/app/http/http-examples.module.ts#L32

```
import { NativeScriptHttpModule } from "nativescript-angular/http";
...
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NativeScriptHttpModule,
        ...
```

> NativeScriptHttpModule is a NativeScript wrapper of Angular’s
>   HttpModule, a module that declares all of Angular’s HTTP-based
>   services...

The usage of wrapper in NativeScript was needed as NativeScript does not "understand" of the DOM web specific properties used in Angular